# After creating a virtualenv with pyenv pip freeze shows packages installed

Tags: pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I'm using pyenv to manage virtualenvs.

I've just create a fresh new virtualenv and activate it using

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.11.2 my-venv
pyenv activate my-venv
```

But when I execute `pip freeze` I got a list of a lot of packages installed instead of the desired empty response.

I checked:

```
$ pyenv which python
/home/miguel/.pyenv/versions/my-venv/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 3.9.13

$ pyenv deactivate
/home/miguel/anaconda3/bin/python
$ pyenv which python
/home/miguel/anaconda3/bin/python
```

I've done this many times in the past, but I'm not sure what is happening now. Do you have any clues?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same problem.

In my case, everything got solved when I uninstalled anaconda. When I set up my PC I'm not sure if I installed conda or pyenv first, but I forgot I had conda installed.

To uninstall conda I followed the official instructions:

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean --yes
```

It takes an instant and there is no need to reopen the shell